# 17.10.1 (VirtualBox) dual monitors not being detected

Tags: virtualbox, 17.10, display, multiple-monitors

I just installed a 17.10.1 VirtualBox.  I go to the display settings and I do not see any "multi monitor" settings.  Is there another place so to activate it?

Comment: Well, *thinking here* the monitors themselves are physical displays (real).  With 16.04, I recall that within the VirtualBox I had set up, it worked just fine.  Just can't recall if I had to do anything special.  It has been quite a while.  Currently, the VM doesn't see the physical displays.     EDIT:: I also set MONITOR COUNT to 2 in the VM settings.

Answer (score 0):

I applied the Guest Additions within the virtual client.  Then selected "seamless mode".  All is as I had expected.